# what is the meaning of this code make -s --eval

Tags: linux, makefile, sudo

Can someone explain this code to me? In detail why these codes were used in the code and what is the purpose of this code in the Linux system

```
COMMAND='/bin/sh'
sudo -u make -s --eval=$'x:\n\t-'"$COMMAND"
```

why this character $'x:\n\t-' ? what the meaning x: and \n and \t-?

what is the goal of this code?

Comment: First of all, do you understand `make` and how to write a makefile? Do you understand what the `-s` option do? What the `--eval` option do? Do you know about the common escape sequences for newline and tab? Have you [read the `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/)? Then think again about what `x:` might symbolize...

Comment: Unless the `sudo` part is important to the question (you want to understand the *whole* part of the command) then please post a new question with it removed. I ask you to post a new question because otherwise if you remove it from this question then the posted answer will become meaningless which isn't very nice. So if the important part of the question is only the `make` command then please post it as a new question without `sudo -u`.

Comment: This looks like a really obscure way to run a root shell; I'm guessing the obfuscation of wrapping it in `make` is trying to hide a back door.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u make -s --eval=$'x:\n\t-'"$COMMAND"
```

is not meaningful. `sudo` usage is:

```
sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt]
     [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
```

So, `make` above is the `user name`, and `--eval` is an invalid option to `sudo`.

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't really answer the question itself, and would be more fitting as a comment.

Comment: @Some programmer dude - The essential question is "what is the meaning of this code". In my opinion, the appropriate answer is "It is not meaningful".

Comment: so the  --eval=$'x:\n\t-' is not doing anything?

Comment: @ALI JASSIM - The `$'x:\n\t-'` is expanded to `x:` _newline_  _tab_ `-`, but this is without effect, since the whole command is aborted.